# How is DeadlineExceededException implemented in Google App Engine for Java?

Tags: java, http, google-app-engine, servlets

Applications on [Google App Engine](http://appengine.google.com/) must have web requests that return response data within 30 seconds. When this time is exceeded, a `DeadlineExceededException` exception is thrown:

```
/time.jsp
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletException
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:754)
    at org.apache.jsp.time_jsp._jspService(time_jsp.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:237)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:830)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:125)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:235)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:4755)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:4753)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.BlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(BlockingApplicationHandler.java:24)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:359)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$2.run(Server.java:800)
    at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanRunnable.run(LocalTraceSpanRunnable.java:56)
    at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanBuilder.internalContinueSpan(LocalTraceSpanBuilder.java:510)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server.startRpc(Server.java:756)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server.processRequest(Server.java:348)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.ServerConnection.messageReceived(ServerConnection.java:459)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcConnection.parseMessages(RpcConnection.java:319)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcConnection.dataReceived(RpcConnection.java:290)
    at com.google.net.async.Connection.handleReadEvent(Connection.java:419)
    at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.processNetworkEvents(EventDispatcher.java:762)
    at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.internalLoop(EventDispatcher.java:207)
    at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.loop(EventDispatcher.java:101)
    at com.google.net.rpc.RpcService.runUntilServerShutdown(RpcService.java:251)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RpcRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:373)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How is it done? Do you have any open source code?

Comment: To put it bluntly, why do you care?

Comment: Uhm... Because humans are curious?

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Because it may be useful for implementing in other (self hosted) apps where the application may do a lot of things with other subsystems (url fetches from other sites, huge lucene index search, deadlocks on database) and you may need to avoid thread starvation using this (brute force) way.

Comment: Now that AppEngine has been open sourced by Google https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-standard , I can find out ! :)

Answer (score 3):

> [The Request Timer](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Request_Timer)
>
> A request handler has a limited amount
>   of time to generate and return a
>   response to a request, typically
>   around 30 seconds. Once the deadline
>   has been reached, the request handler
>   is interrupted.
>
> The **Java runtime environment**
>   interrupts the servlet by throwing a
>   com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException.
>   If the request handler does not catch
>   this exception, as with all uncaught
>   exceptions, the runtime environment
>   will return an HTTP 500 server error
>   to the client.
>
> The request handler can catch this
>   error to customize the response. The
>   runtime environment gives the request
>   handler a little bit more time (less
>   than a second) after raising the
>   exception to prepare a custom
>   response.
>
> While a request can take as long as 30
>   seconds to respond, App Engine is
>   optimized for applications with
>   short-lived requests, typically those
>   that take a few hundred milliseconds.
>   An efficient app responds quickly for
>   the majority of requests. An app that
>   doesn't will not scale well with App
>   Engine's infrastructure.

Part of the runtime == Not using threads. This feature is a modification of the VM for sure, and I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the mechanism behind this exception is implemented in app engine infrastructure, that is not open source.

However you can use this feature for networking or more generally any I/O bounded code using [java.nio](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) (e.g [Selector](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html)). Instead for CPU bounded code you can use [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) (e.g. [Future](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows, use [non-blocking IO](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/nio/), and create a watchdog thread which records the startup time and throws the Exception when the elapsed time has passed.  The non-blocking IO tutorial shows how this can be done with the [Ping.java](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/nio/example/Ping.java) example.

Comment: The question asks how GAE does it. Google says it is implemented in the runtime. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Request_Timer

Answer (score 1):

May be a very late reply, but useful for new learners.

```
@Override
protected final void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {

    res.setContentType("text/html");
    final PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    final String a = req.getParameter("a");
    try {

        for (int i = 0; 1 < 5; i++) {
            out.print("Mode " + a + " Running " + i + " " + MainServlon.doubleIt(i));
            Thread.sleep(90000);
        }

    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final DeadlineExceededException e) {
        out.print("Train is going to stop. Let me close this story for now!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Question was about how the exception is thrown for every request/servlet > 30s, not how to catch it.